# How to print the index number of an element in two dimensional arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, shuffle, indexof

So this is the code, i displayed a multiple of 5 and then shuffled it.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TwoDimensionalArrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {
```

This part is the display of multiple of 5 numbers up to 500.

```
        int [][]table = new int[10][10];

        int x = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < table[i].length; j++){
                table[i][j]= x;
                x+=5;

                System.out.print(table[i][j] +  "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

This part is the shuffled arrays using Math.random.

```
        System.out.println("\nShuffled Arrays: \n");
        int index1 = 0;

        for(int a = 0; a < table.length; a++) {
            for(int b = 0; b < table[a].length; b++) {
                int il = (int)(Math.random()*table.length);
                int jl = (int)(Math.random()*table[a].length);

                int temp = table[a][b];
                table[a][b] = table[il][jl];
                table[il][jl] = temp;

                System.out.print(table[a][b] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

   }
```

How can i print the index number of an element, for example, 40, from the shuffled arrays?

Comment: What do you mean by 'index number'?  Is '40' equal to an index of (4,0), or are you saying (starting from (0,0), (0,1), ..., (0,n), (1,0), ..., that it is the 40th item encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below answer. Here I added seperate `for` loops to print the shuffled array. Because in your current implementation after printing `table[a][b]` value, that value can be gain replaced by the randomly generated indexes. So Best way is print the shuffled array after completely shuffled it. Used `Map<String, Integer>` to keep the indexes with values. Please check the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] table = new int[10][10];

    int x = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            table[i][j] = x;
            x += 5;

            System.out.print(table[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\nShuffled Arrays: \n");

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); //Hash map to keep indexes

    //Shuffle the array
    for (int a = 0; a < table.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < table[a].length; b++) {
            int il = (int) (Math.random() * table.length);
            int jl = (int) (Math.random() * table[a].length);
            int temp = table[a][b];
            table[a][b] = table[il][jl];
            table[il][jl] = temp;
        }
    }

    //Print shuffled array
    for (int a = 0; a < table.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < table[a].length; b++) {
            int value = table[a][b];
            System.out.print(value + "\t");

            //Insert indexes to hash map as key value pairs
            String key = a + ", " + b;
            if (value == 40 || value == 320 || value == 450) {
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    //Printing indexes
    System.out.println("\nIndexes: \n");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " [" + entry.getKey() + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: @InspiritC please accept this answer, if it solves your problem by ticking the right arrow near the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the idea here is to check if value on random index is present in existing array(before shuffled), if yes then add the random entry into a map with value as newly assigned index in shuffled array, so this way once your shuffled array is ready, you have the completed map with all the details of each value and its index in shuffled array

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    int [][]table = new int[10][10];

    Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();

    int x = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < table[i].length; j++){
            table[i][j]= x;
            x+=5;

            System.out.print(table[i][j] +  "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("\nShuffled Arrays: \n");
    int index1 = 0;

    for(int a = 0; a < table.length; a++) {
        for(int b = 0; b < table[a].length; b++) {
            int il = (int)(Math.random()*table.length);
            int jl = (int)(Math.random()*table[a].length);

            int temp = table[a][b];

            if(exists(table[il][jl], table)) {
                map.put(table[il][jl], "["+a + "][" + b + "]");
            }

            table[a][b] = table[il][jl];

            table[il][jl] = temp;

            System.out.print(table[a][b] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println(map);     
}

public static boolean exists(int value, int[][] tmp) {
    List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(tmp);
    for(int[] arr: list){
        if(Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(i -> i == value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this will help..!!